# How do I take over an existing FB App from prior developer?

Tags: facebook

Does anyone know who I contact to migrate an existing app to a different FB login? Or do I just create new apps under my development pages, use the new api keys and ignore the prior items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current admin/developer needs to get to the [Developer App](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) and add you as  a new admin for the app. Then you can remove the old admin from the administrator list.

There needs at least to be one admin per app, so an admin can't remove himself from the app unless he adds a new admin who accepts the request.

Comment: The prior developer would not help so I created a new app key and used it instead.  I was worried that creating a second app key for the same site may cause an issue on Facebook's side but this was not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the new person as an administrator in the app settings and have them remove you

Don't try to remove yourself in case you do that before the other person accepts